# I need code review on using singleton to access local database

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, singleton

As I get to some performance issues in my app and find that I use database access in a bad way.
So I decided to move to singleton pattern.
I need someone to review this code and confirm me that I made a good database access via singleton pattern or I am doing something wrong:
This is the class:

```
@interface DataAccessController : NSObject{
    sqlite3 *databaseHandle;
}
+ (id)sharedManager;
-(void)initDatabase;
...
+ (id)sharedManager {
    static DataAccessController *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self initDatabase]; // open database connection
    }
    return self;
}
...
```

AppDelegate.m

```
DataAccessController *d = [DataAccessController sharedManager];
```

Usage through the application every time I need data I use:

```
DataAccessController *d = [DataAccessController sharedManager];
NSMutableArray* data = [d getAllRecordedUnits];
```

Comment: There isn't much to review there; however if your performance issues are because you open then close the database "connection" for every query then that will obviously cause a performance issue.  You need to  keep the database open for as long as possible, and perhaps just close it when the app goes into the background.

Comment: I can't close it in background because I save coordinates while app is in background. My concern about above code is am I doing it right that I get singleton instance in functions where I need database access or I should maybe declare that somewhere so I can everywhere just type "[d someFunction]"?

Comment: Yes taking above code in consideration everything looks nice

Comment: Why is this tagged with [core-data]? I cannot see any Core Data code in the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with database access is not whether you use a singleton pattern or not, but **whether you access the database always from the main thread or also from other threads**.

In fact, in most situations I use a singleton for database access (albeit by keeping the database connection in my app delegate). But you should make sure you always access the database on the main thread (which might be not performing well if you access it a lot and from different threads), or keep different contexts for different threads, synching them where needed.

Have a look here for an explanation:

[Apple Core Data Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

[Apple Core Data Performance Considerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW1)

[Apple Core Data Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1)